# Liferay deploy backup with changes in database

Tags: deployment, liferay, liferay-6

When I'd modified or create new tables in Liferay 6.1 and deploy in production server. Liferay automatically makes a backup of each table.

This backup takes a long time when a table has more than 10k records. And a century when has 100k. Although this table hasn't been modified.

What can I do for optimice the deployment to the server?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment I think only two options are available:

1. (easy way) Set "build.auto.upgrade=false" in /WEB-INF/src/service.properties to avoid any automatic updates, and perform the db changes (if any) manually.
2. (hard way) Reworite the Liferays ServiceBuilder so that it perform an update only on those tables which were changed. This will require an EXT development as it is a very core change, and for every next Liferay version you will need to carefully review it and upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the easy one. I prefer don't touch the core of Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay automatically makes a backup? Where to? This is new to me!

Also, you're describing a "no go" operation: You don't modify any tables in the database. Period. That's what the API is there for. If you do, prepare for disaster, sooner (if you're lucky) or later (according to Murphy, when you forgot that you changed manually. Then you'll blame Liferay for the failure that you caused by manipulating the database).

Do you have your own backup routine implemented that runs on every server restart? This is the only thing that I can imagine to happen here - in that case you'll need to modify your backup strategy. Or the database that you use - maybe a transaction log backup makes more sense than duplicating the table content into the same database...